# How to set NA values to other row value within same grouping in R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing Parts grouped by Material, Client, CompanyCode, and STOCK_UOM. For each FiscalYear there is an associated column for WAP (weighted average price). FiscalYear 2022 should have the value of WAP_2021 (and associated type) in the WaP column. FiscalYear 2023 should have the value of WAP_2022 (and associated type) in the WaP column. But where FiscalYear is 2023 there can be NA values for WAP_2022, in this case it should give the value of the previous year WaP (WAP_2021).

| Material | Client | CompanyCode | STOCK_UOM | FiscalYear | WAP_2021 | WAP_2021_Type | WAP_2022 | WAP_2022_Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Cl1 | 1010 | EA | 2022 | 13.1 | WAP 2021 | NA | NA |
| 1234 | Cl1 | 1010 | EA | 2023 | NA | NA | NA | WAP 2022 |

Desired Result:

| Material | Client | CompanyCode | STOCK_UOM | FiscalYear | WaP | WaPType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Cl1 | 1010 | EA | 2022 | 13.1 | WAP 2021 |
| 1234 | Cl1 | 1010 | EA | 2023 | 13.1 | WAP 2022 |

I have added a mutate statement to handle the first part.

```r
df %>% mutate(WaP = ifelse(FiscalYear == 2022, WAP_2021, WAP_2022),
              WaPType = ifelse(FiscalYear == 2022, WAP_2021_Type, WAP_2022_Type))
```

Now I need to replace the NA values in this WaP column with the associated value for that Material, Client, CompanyCode, UOM from the WAP_2021 column. How do I reference certain rows based on this criteria? I would need the same group (Material, etc) but for FiscalYear 2022.

Answer (score 0):

You could first delete years from the `names`,

```
names(dat) <- gsub('_\\d{4}', '', names(dat))
```

and create a blank with `unique` names and zero rows, with which we want to `merge` later on.

```
blank <- matrix(, nrow=0, ncol=length(unique(names(dat))),
                dimnames=list(NULL, unique(names(dat))))
```

Next, `by` fiscal year, we just select columns that are not only `NA`s and `merge` it with the blank to globally get the same `names`. We `rbind` the result. Finally we `zoo::na.locf` the WAP column.

```
by(dat, dat$FiscalYear, \(x) x[colSums(is.na(x)) == 0]) |>
  lapply(merge, blank, all=TRUE) |>
  do.call(what=rbind) |>
  transform(WAP=zoo::na.locf(WAP))
#      Material Client CompanyCode STOCK_UOM FiscalYear  WAP WAP_Type
# 2022     1234    Cl1        1010        EA       2022 13.1 WAP 2021
# 2023     1234    Cl1        1010        EA       2023 13.1 WAP 2022
```

Comment: There could be other WAP Types other than WAP 2021 or WAP 2022, but I think your first point in order to use blank and merge is a good idea still. The issue is that if WAP_2022 is NA we need to use WAP_2021 and set the WaP_Type to whatever the WAP_2021_Type is. The types are never NA but the WAP could be for FY 2023. 
Also, is there a way to order the data before doing the na.locf? If I were to have multiple different materials, then it just pulls the last place WAP is not NA which wouldn't necessarily be for the right Material, Client, CoCode, UOM.